# LWC Public Method on Imported Component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have one LWC component that is using the import functionality to pull in another LWC component.
The imported component has a public method exposed via the @api decorator.

The code is as follows (I boiled it down to make it more digestible):

**Component that gets imported**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getPricingData from '@salesforce/apex/CustomPricingService.getPricingData';

export default class CustomPricing extends LightningElement {

    _productId;

    @wire(getPricingData, {productId:`$_productId`}) pricingData;

    @api getPricing(pricingType, inputs){
        this._productId = inputs.productId;
    }
}
```

**Component that performs the import**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import CustomPricing from 'c/customPricing';

export default class UsesCustomPricing extends LightningElement {

    handleButtonClick(buttonEvent){
        CustomPricing.getPricing( 'myType', { productId: '01t000000000000000' });
    }
}
```

When the public method is invoked, there is an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: CustomPricing__default.default.getPricing is not a function throws at https://sandboxname--c.visualforce.com/auraFW/javascript/Q3onN6EmJyHRC52_NEPe2B/aura_proddebug.js:11107:11
```

I logged the imported component to the console and saw that it was just a class that was imported. So I tried to create a new instance of the class to try and invoke the public method as shown below:

**Component that performs the import - Revision 1**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import CustomPricing from 'c/customPricing';

export default class UsesCustomPricing extends LightningElement {

    handleButtonClick(buttonEvent){
        let newInstance = new CustomPricing();
        newInstance.getPricing( 'myType', { productId: '01t000000000000000' });
    }
}
```

It results in an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Illegal constructor throws at https://sandboxname--c.visualforce.com/auraFW/javascript/Q3onN6EmJyHRC52_NEPe2B/aura_proddebug.js:11107:11
```

So I feel like I have a few options.

1. Just directly add the imported component to the markup of the
   importing component instead of importing it in the JS file. Then would just need to do a `this.template.querySelectorAll('c-custom-pricing')[0].getPricing('myType',{productId:'01t000000000000000'});` But this doesn't feel right and I'd like to learn the correct way to address this issue.
2. Modify the imported component to no longer export a class and
   instead have it export a function. But then I lose the LWC caching
   from the @wire functionality that I intentionally want.
3. Try to figure out a way to export a function from the CustomPricing
   component that can somehow interact with the CustomPricing class
   which would allow the caching from @wire to function. Would be
   similar to

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getPricingData from '@salesforce/apex/CustomPricingService.getPricingData';

export default class CustomPricing extends LightningElement {

    productId;

    @wire(getPricingData, {productId:`$productId`}) pricingData;

    @api getPricing(pricingType, inputs){
        this.productId = inputs.productId;
    }
}

export function myFunction(pricingType, inputs){

    let newInstance = new CustomPricing();
    return newInstance.getPricing(pricingType, inputs);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An imperative Apex call would probably be more appropriate here:

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getPricingData from '@salesforce/apex/CustomPricingService.getPricingData';
_cache = {}
export function getPriceData(productId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(_cache[productId]) {
      refreshApex(_cache[productId]).then(
        result => (_cache[productId] = result, resolve(result.data))
      ).catch(error => reject(error));
    } else {
      getPricingData({productId}).then(
        result => (_cache[productId] = result, resolve(result.data))
      ).catch(error => reject(error));
   });
}
```

Which then makes your dependent code:

```
import { getPriceData } from 'c/customPricing';
...
handleButtonClick(event) {
  try {
    let pricingData = await getPriceData(event.target.dataset.productId);
    ...
  } catch(e) {
    // deal with error here
  }
}
```

You should not try to extend a LightningElement unless a component is a real UI component. You can still use the export default class design if you want, but I don't believe wire methods work properly across classes, hence the imperative calls.